# Как вытаскивать строки из базы данных исключая некоторые из них?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть вот такая функция:

```
def funciton():
    list = [1, 3, 5]
    with sq.connect(database_path) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        id = cur.execute(f"select row from table where id != {list} order by random() limit 1").fetchone()
        print(id)
```

Мне нужно чтобы она вытащила из базы данных 1 случайную запись, но при этом если id этом записи будет в списке list то пропустить эту запись и выбрать ту где id не равно тем которые записанные в список list

Подскажите возможно ли такое сделать, и как?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def funciton():
    list = (1, 3, 5)
    with sq.connect(database_path) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        id = cur.execute(f"select row from table where id not in {tuple(list)} order by random() limit 1").fetchone()
        print(id)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать связать список ID для пропуска напрямую с запросом, не забыв при этом обработать его до приемлемого состояния:

```py
def funciton():
    lst = [1, 3, 5]
    with sq.connect(database_path) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(lst))
        id = cur.execute("select * from table where id not in (%s) order by random() limit 1")
             % format_strings, tuple(lst)).fetchone()
        print(id)
```

Я опирался на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589416) ответ из англоязычной SO, т.к., по сути говоря, идея там схожа с текущей — правда, там нужно было стереть все данные с ID, имеющимися в таблице, а здесь — выбрать те, которые НЕ имебтся в таблице.